# how to update values in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am going to update My permission table value.

this is controlller function

```
public function edit($project,$id)
 {

   $projectId=Project::findOrFail($project, ['id'])->id;
   $permissions = Permission::permissioneditt($id,$projectId)->get();
 view('collaborators.permissionedit')->withPermissions($permissions);
     return view('collaborators.permissionedit', compact('permissions', 'projectId','collaborator->user()->first()->id'));



 }
```

and this is update function

```
public function update(Request $request, $projectId, $collaboratorId)
 {
    $this->validate($request, [
            'status'  => 'required',
        ]);

        DB::table('permissions')
            ->where('project_id', $projectId)
            ->where('collaborator_id', $collaboratorId)
            ->update(['status' => $request->input('status')]);

        return redirect()->back()->with('info','Your Permission has been updated successfully');



 }
```

this is update form

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{url('projects/' .$projectId .'/collaborators/' . $collaboratorId.'}}">



<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('status') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="status" class="control-label">Choose Permission</label>
                <select name="status" id="status">
                    <option value="{!! $permission->status !!}">{!! $permission->status !!}</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    {{ getStatus($permission->status) }}
                </select>
                @if ($errors->has('status'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('status') }}</span>
                @endif
              {{--  {{$permission->project_id}} --}}

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            {!! method_field('PUT') !!}
</form>
```

and this is routes

```
Route::put('projects/{projects}/collaborators/{id}',['uses'=>'ProjectCollaboratorsController@update',]);
```

but when I click update button it is generated following error

```
FatalErrorException in 607c064f09cf795b94deb14e18a3a34650c521d0.php line 23: syntax error, unexpected 'status' (T_STRING)
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Grab the value of `$request->input('status')` in a variable and then pass it to the query builder

Comment: can you put code here it is great help

Comment: Change your update function according to this: http://pastebin.com/pyZrVvSN and give this a shot